# for Loop not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Only show last image when I open it in browser help why loop not working?

```
var i=0;
function set()
{
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + ".jpg"+"  width='500' height='300' style='margin-left:400px;' />";   
        document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = image;        
    }
}
setInterval("set()","600");

        <div id="slider">   
            <img src="images/sl1.jpg" />
        </div>
```

I make a simple slider in javascript but when i run this its only show me the last images from my images folder like i have 5 images sl1 | sl2 |...sl5 ...
its only me last image 5th ... loop not working..

Comment: What makes you think the loop doesn't work?

Comment: Not working is never a good enough description

Comment: Not a solution, but *DON'T* pass strings to `setInterval`.  Is uses `eval`!  Pass functions.  `setInterval(set, 600);`.

Comment: So, what *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you have a loop?  Why `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
function setImage(i) {
    var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + ".jpg" + "  width='500' height='300' style='margin-left:400px;' />";
    document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = image;
}

function loopImages(i) {
    setImage(i);    //    set current Image

    if (i == 5) {    
      i = 1;    //  reset the counter
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        loopImages(i++);
    }, "600");    //    set next image in 600 ms

}

loopImages(1);
```

Don't know if you want it to stop on image 5 or to loop forever...

Answer (score 1):

You have to append to the `innerHTML`, not just set it.

```
var slider =document.getElementById("slider");
slider.innerHTML = slider.innerHTML + image;
```

Comment: ok then tell me how can I append???

Comment: @UmerBest: Change the `=` to `+=` :-)

Comment: Also! You need to clear out the innerHTML at the beginning of each `set` call!

Comment: This is not what the OP (most likely) wants to do. I bet they want the image to change every 600 ms, not append the same set of 5 images to the HTML every 600 ms.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `+=` is slower. http://jsperf.com/plus-equals-new-vs-equals-old-plus-new

Comment: @DanielA.White: Not really.  I tested this and Opera says they are both the same.  Chrome said it was 1% faster.

Comment: Depends on what version of browser you're running. Those results are inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every time you change the DOM, the browser has to re-render the page. For better performance, just do that once by storing the new html in a temporary var.
2. The first parameter to setInterval should be a function name, not a string.

```
var i=0;
function set()
{
    var new_html = '';
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + ".jpg"+"  width='500' height='300' style='margin-left:400px;' />";   
        new_html += image;        
    }
    document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = new_html
}
setInterval(set,600);

<div id="slider">   
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: But why run the same function every 600 ms that does exactly the same thing? Are you sure this is what the OP wants the code to do?

Comment: I have no idea what the OP actually wants. I have a feeling this entire question is a X-Y Problem.

Comment: the interval delay is actually a number not a string

Comment: lol I missed that too. Good catch.